# ¿Cómo eliminar espacios o posicionar correctamente imagen svg?

Tags: svg

Existe un problema al diseñar esta imagen vectorial al parecer son espacios o error de posicionamiento de la imagen vectorial.

> Los errores no son en los estilos `css` el problema solo ocurre en la siguiente imagen.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
<path d="M303.599,261.663v37.75c0,1.81-1.475,3.291-3.285,3.291h-18.626c-1.801,0-3.275-1.48-3.275-3.291     v-37.75c0-1.812,1.475-3.291,3.275-3.291h3.51v-8.199c-0.041-20.686-16.774-37.425-37.466-37.45h-18.483     c-20.691,0.025-37.415,16.765-37.455,37.45v8.199h3.855c1.811,0,3.286,1.479,3.286,3.291v37.75c0,1.81-1.475,3.291-3.286,3.291     h-4.059c3.306,10.289,12.939,17.74,24.332,17.761h5.92v-1.403c0-1.45,1.18-2.747,2.624-2.879l12.512-1.155     c1.455-0.132,3.998,1.328,3.998,7.243s-2.544,7.029-3.998,6.897l-12.512-1.165c-1.444-0.122-2.624-1.424-2.624-2.874v-1.389     h-5.92c-13.224,0-24.373-8.905-27.781-21.036h-11.108c-1.8,0-3.286-1.48-3.286-3.291v-37.75c0-1.812,1.485-3.291,3.286-3.291     h9.827v-8.199c0-23.402,18.981-42.379,42.389-42.379h18.483c23.417,0,42.389,18.977,42.389,42.379v8.199h10.193     C302.124,258.372,303.599,259.852,303.599,261.663z" style="fill:#777777;"/>

<path d="M264.181,265.691h-4.15c-1.302,0-2.35,1.048-2.35,2.34v9.638c0,1.298,1.048,2.345,2.35,2.345h4.15     c1.302,0,2.35-1.047,2.35-2.345v-9.638C266.53,266.739,265.482,265.691,264.181,265.691z" style="fill:#484B4D;"/>

<path d="M211.792,265.691c-1.292,0-2.34,1.048-2.34,2.34v9.638c0,1.298,1.048,2.345,2.34,2.345h4.171     c1.292,0,2.339-1.047,2.339-2.345v-9.638c0-1.292-1.047-2.34-2.339-2.34H211.792z" style="fill:#484B4D;"/>

</svg>
```

En esta siguiente imagen vectorial no ocasiona problema.

```html
<svg id="8827bb75-1d28-4473-954e-960dfc3694a7" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28.48231 33.6619"><title>erp</title><rect x="0.5" y="23.65583" width="27.42157" height="9.50608" rx="0.80219" ry="0.80219" style="fill:none;stroke:#45beeb;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"/><path d="M3763.981,2725.52925h-25.44813a1.56423,1.56423,0,0,1-1.56423-1.56423v-6.37761a1.56423,1.56423,0,0,1,1.56423-1.56423h5.01593" transform="translate(-3736.46867 -2709.18579)" style="fill:none;stroke:#45beeb;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"/><polyline points="13.236 5.375 18.05 10.311 27.982 0.5" style="fill:none;stroke:#45beeb;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"/></svg>
```

El problema que ocasiona la imagen vectorial es la imagen **support**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** Los bordes donde se encuentra la imagen vectorial son los mismo con el error que ocasiona la imagen **support** en todas las imágenes vectoriales el único problema el que ocasiona es la imagen vectorial **support.**

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN** por pedido de [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46999/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-espacios-o-posicionar-correctamente-imagen-svg?noredirect=1#comment81991_46999)

El estilo **CSS** es el siguiente:

```
.Fleft {
  float:left;
}

/*EL BORDE DEL CUADRO DONDE SE ENCUENTRA LA IMAGEN*/
.icon-big {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
}

/*LA MANERA DE CÓMO OBTENGO LAS IMÁGENES VECTORIALES*/
.icon-support {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(../img/system/gray/support.svg);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

En el **HTML**

```
<div class="icon-big Fleft"><i class="icon-support"></i></div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código HTML+CSS que falla con las imágenes SVG?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro Editado la pregunta aunque el problema no es en el **HTML/CSS.**

Comment: Te estaba poniendo un comentario cuando editaste la pregunta. [No podía duplicar el problema](https://jsfiddle.net/8efzsq5k/), voy a probar con tu código. Gracias

Comment: Sigo sin poder reproducir el problema en local. Esto es lo que veo cuando ejecuto tu código: http://i.imgur.com/FaNnvgB.png

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro El problema ahí del ejemplo es que la imagen vectorial quedan muy pequeña, yo juego con el tamaño deseado en la **class** `.icon-support` mediante `width: 40px; height: 40px;`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro debes guardar el código `svg` en un archivo **support.svg** y llamarlo a las clases que he proporcionado.

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy haciendo y el resultado es el que te muestro en la imagen enlazada. Esto se puede considerar un error de CSS porque se puede solucionar cambiando el tamaño del fondo a 200% y posicionando el fondo en el centro

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro El problema presenta en cambiar el tamaño de la imagen al cambiarla porque si la dejo en modo de ejemplo que me has dejado se ve demasiado pequeña y al cambiar el tamaño no se adapta o es decir existe espacio en la imagen vectorial que no deja adaptarla como ocurre en el resto de la imagen vectoriales que no ocasiona problema por otra parte el procedimiento que has realizado en el ejemplo es muy distinto al mi procedimiento [https://jsfiddle.net/8efzsq5k/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/8efzsq5k/1/)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52820/discussion-between-alvaro-montoro-and-j-mick).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro En el ejemplo que te he proporcionado he cambiado el tamaño de la imagen a 140px X140px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifique el SVG, esperando que asi funcione sobre tu HTML

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 500 500"
   id="svg2">
  <defs
     id="defs12" />
  <path
     d="m 481.5651,209.85405 v 135.06579 c 0,6.47601 -5.2774,11.77488 -11.75341,11.77488 h -66.642 c -6.4438,0 -11.71763,-5.2953 -11.71763,-11.77488 V 209.85405 c 0,-6.48316 5.2774,-11.77488 11.71763,-11.77488 h 12.55843 V 168.74395 C 415.58143,94.731467 355.71239,34.840962 281.67844,34.751514 H 215.54807 C 141.51769,34.840962 81.680857,94.735045 81.537741,168.74395 v 29.33522 h 13.792813 c 6.479576,0 11.756986,5.29172 11.756986,11.77488 v 135.06579 c 0,6.47601 -5.27741,11.77488 -11.756986,11.77488 H 80.807848 c 11.828545,36.81304 46.294482,63.47199 87.057522,63.54712 h 21.18118 v -5.0198 c 0,-5.18795 4.22192,-9.82849 9.38841,-10.30078 l 44.76671,-4.13247 c 5.20585,-0.47229 14.30446,4.75145 14.30446,25.91474 0,21.16329 -9.10219,25.14908 -14.30446,24.67679 l -44.76671,-4.16825 c -5.16649,-0.43651 -9.38841,-5.09493 -9.38841,-10.28289 v -4.96971 h -21.18118 c -47.31418,0 -87.204216,-31.86122 -99.397706,-75.26475 H 28.724326 c -6.440224,0 -11.756987,-5.2953 -11.756987,-11.77488 V 209.85405 c 0,-6.48316 5.313185,-11.77488 11.756987,-11.77488 h 35.160045 v -29.33522 c 0,-83.730065 67.912159,-151.627916 151.663699,-151.627916 h 66.13037 c 83.78374,0 151.6637,67.897851 151.6637,151.627916 v 29.33522 h 36.46955 c 6.47601,0 11.75341,5.2953 11.75341,11.77488 z"
     id="path4"
     style="fill:#777777" />
  <path
     d="m 340.53135,224.26584 h -14.84829 c -4.65843,0 -8.40807,3.74964 -8.40807,8.37229 v 34.48382 c 0,4.64412 3.74964,8.39018 8.40807,8.39018 h 14.84829 c 4.65843,0 8.40807,-3.74606 8.40807,-8.39018 v -34.48382 c -0.004,-4.62265 -3.75322,-8.37229 -8.40807,-8.37229 z"
     id="path6"
     style="fill:#484b4d" />
  <path
     d="m 153.08863,224.26584 c -4.62265,0 -8.37229,3.74964 -8.37229,8.37229 v 34.48382 c 0,4.64412 3.74964,8.39018 8.37229,8.39018 h 14.92343 c 4.62265,0 8.36871,-3.74606 8.36871,-8.39018 v -34.48382 c 0,-4.62265 -3.74606,-8.37229 -8.36871,-8.37229 h -14.92343 z"
     id="path8"
     style="fill:#484b4d" />
</svg>
```

El procedimiento que realize fue abrirlo en Inkscape y lo escale a que usara el 100% del `viewbox`, como veras al guardarlo inkscape usa path relativos en lugar de absolutos, por lo cual tendras cambios drasticos en el `path`

---

Con la propiedad `stroke-width` puedes hacer los bordes mas finos

Comment: Hola @jasilva Funciona perfectamente, tengo el programa de **Inkscape ** hace unos días atrás lo instale pero aun no se como usarlo, podrías decirme que pasos hiciste en el programa para que la imagen vectorial tenga esos cambios deseados.

Comment: por cierto amigo en aquel programa puedo perfeccionar también los bordes de la imagen para obtener unos bordes más delgados o más fino porque en esta ocasión las propiedades `stroke-width: 0.1px;
    width: 1px;` no funciona podrias mencionar aquello en tu pregunta si no es mucho pedir amigo.

Comment: Con "F1" selecciona todos los path( en este caso tres) y cuandos esten todos selecionados, apareceran 8 flechas para escalar y las arrastras, para mover todo proporcionalmente, puedes ver [aqui](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26892/inkscape-scale-with-keep-aspect-ratio-as-default)

Comment: parece fácil, amigo y con **Inkscape** también es posible editar los bordes o perfeccionar los bordes a más delgado/fino las líneas del dibujo se puede o no.

Comment: @J.Mick Si lo recomendables es crear los svg en un editor, ya que es muy complejo estar manipulando los path a mano. Para el stroke trata de usar `stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-opacity:1` aunque opacity en teoria por defaul es 1

Comment: es verdad pero en algunas ocasiones es más factibles manipular los path a mano con la simple propiedad de stroke-width:1; lo soluciona todo sin tener que editar en un editor. EL PROBLEMA ES QUE EN UNAS OCASIONES NO FUNCIONA LA PROPIEDAD COMO EN ESTE CASO. por eso te mencionaba si con el **Inkscape** existe alguna función que lo perfeccione automáticamente.

Comment: Pues dentro de Inkscape, puedes manipular casi todo el SVG. No deberia eixtir un caso en el que `stroke-width` no funcione, en esos caso deberias checar la sintaxis de tu svg para versi hay algun `"` o `>` perdido. Pero en el caso de inkscape como es un editor WYVIWYG no queda duda cuando se aplican los elementos

Answer (score 2):

He copiado la imagen y la he guardado en un [SVG](http://alvaromontoro.com/images/support.svg) en un servidor que tengo online. Entonces he puesto tu código:

```css
.Fleft {
  float:left;
}

/*EL BORDE DEL CUADRO DONDE SE ENCUENTRA LA IMAGEN*/
.icon-big {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
}

/*LA MANERA DE CÓMO OBTENGO LAS IMÁGENES VECTORIALES*/
.icon-support {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://alvaromontoro.com/images/support.svg);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-big Fleft"><i class="icon-support"></i></div>
```

Y la imagen se ve muy pequeña, pero como lo muestras en tu imagen. Si cambias el CSS para que la imagen de fondo tenga un tamaño más grande y esté centrada (con `background-size` y `background-position` respectivamente) el problema se resuelve:

```css
.Fleft {
  float:left;
}

/*EL BORDE DEL CUADRO DONDE SE ENCUENTRA LA IMAGEN*/
.icon-big {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d7d7d7;
}

/*LA MANERA DE CÓMO OBTENGO LAS IMÁGENES VECTORIALES*/
.icon-support {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://alvaromontoro.com/images/support.svg);
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-big Fleft"><i class="icon-support"></i></div>
```

Comment: Es una muy buena opción amigo pero por otra parte la imagen vectorial quedaría con aquel problema, sigue con el tema para aclarar cual era en realidad el problema un +1 por una segunda alternativa gracias.

Comment: @J.Mick Si lo que quieres es editar la imagen, puedes abrirla con GIMP, cortarla y exportar los paths. Es un método rápido, aunque el código no será tan limpio como el que tienes. Pero creo que también te serviría: http://alvaromontoro.com/images/support2.svg

Comment: Gracias amigo otro programa muy interesante que lo tendre encuenta a la hora de editar y diseñar imágenes vectoriales. pero al parecer **Inkscape** es mucho más mejor o más limpio e optimizado como se puede observar en la respuesta de **jasilva** la imagen la edito con este programa  **Inkscape.**